# spring-boot graal native on aws lambda

Tags: spring-boot, aws-lambda, graalvm-native-image

im trying to migrate an existing code from spring-boot on aws lambda without success

without "graal" my jar doesn't have a Main class instead i have a class implementing RequestStreamHandler and the lambda handler point to its handleRequest method so far so good.

now when im building spring as native i need to supply a main class.

i have tried to create a simple main with

```
package com.kotless.spring.boot.graal

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    SpringApplication.run(Application::class.java, *args)                                
}
```

ended up with "stuck lambda" (i can see in the logs that tomcat is ready but it doesnt recieve the actual rest call).

so i digged a bit and saw i should add property as:
`spring.main.web-application-type=none`

which ended up with my lambda going up - everything is set and later it goes down resolving in unexpected exit:

```
2023-12-23T17:33:50.099Z  INFO 11 --- [           main] com.kotless.spring.boot.graal.MainKt     : Started MainKt in 0.153 seconds (process running for 0.499)
2023-12-23T17:33:50.100Z  INFO 11 --- [           main] c.a.s.p.i.servlet.AwsServletContext      : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-12-23T17:33:50.100Z  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
2023-12-23T17:33:50.100Z  INFO 11 --- [           main] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
INIT_REPORT Init Duration: 539.44 ms    Phase: init Status: error   Error Type: Runtime.ExitError
```

im missing something basic here but im not sure what exactly as i do implement the RequestStreamHandler

in addition i have tried setting a "@Bean" for the "RequestStreamHandler"

Comment: so it seems i was missing the lambda custom even loop.

Comment: i found what i was looking for here:

https://github.com/AlexanderPrendota/kcdk-runtimes/tree/master/runtimes/runtime-graalvm

Answer (score 0):

Your library is too old (4 years ago). Use current version, JDK 21, GraalVM 21.